# lite version of app won't start because it can't bind to service (full version also installed)

Tags: android

I had just finished building my app, and everything runs great. So I decided to create a lite version of it as well. I converted my android project to an android library and created a lite project and a full project that each reference the library.

I ran my full version this way and it worked great. I then tried to run my lite version and it complains with "SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent..."

It's referring to the local service that I bind to from each activity.

I'm guessing that because the service has the same package name in both apps, the lite app gets confused and tries to connect to the full app's service...

How can I fix this with as little disruption as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seeing as I got no replies... I thought I'd share what I ended up doing. My suspicion was correct about the services requiring unique package names if deployed in two applications.

So instead of a library and two projects I now just have one single android project. Within that I have a static flag constant that I change depending what I want to run. I generate an APK with the flag turned off in one case. Then I rename the package for the entire project (eclipse refactoring) and generate another APK with the flag turned on.

When the flag is on, some parts of the application are locked (so lite version). When it's off it's the full version.

Once I'm done, I revert to base and erase all my changes.

This isn't the ideal solution I was hoping for, but it only takes a minute to do. So it's not a big deal.